# C++ compile error in xlocale in vxworks

Tags: c++, vxworks

I am compiling a C++ code on Vxworks6.8 and i am facing with following error

```
d:/windri~1/gnu/412-vx~1.8/lib/gcc/../../include/c++/4.1/xlocale: In function 'const _Facet& std::use_facet(const std::locale&) [with _Facet = std::ctype<char>]':
1>d:/WindRiver/gnu/4.1.2-vxworks-6.8/lib/gcc/../../include/c++/4.1/xlocale(1341) : error: instantiated from here
1>d:/WindRiver/gnu/4.1.2-vxworks-6.8/lib/gcc/../../include/c++/4.1/xlocale(316) : error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
```

I am not sure why i am facing with above error? what feature in C++ will call use_facet mentioned in above error?

I have no clue how to solve above error so any inputs are welcome. Thanks for your inputs. 
for your information i am not supposed to enable exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are using some Standard headers such as `<iostream>`. STL and Standard Library heavily uses exceptions, so if you want to disable them you will be unable to use most of the features of Standard Library.

Comment: yes, you are right, i am using STL string, after i commented these changes error is gone. Thanks for saving my weekend.